# Enable or disable a task based on parameter

Tags: ssis, parameter

I have an SSIS package called Main_Flow that executes several other packages in order.

What I'd like to do is to somehow parametrise the enabling/disabling of packages in the main flow. This way I can choose to skip certain tasks based on value of parameters upon execution.

How can I ensure that a task can be skipped if DisabeTaskA parameter is set to TRUE?

It is important to emphasize that if I disable a package in the middle of the linear sequence, although this task would be skipped this does not mean any of the next packages should be skipped (unless I opted to disable them). That is, the skip shouldn't break out of the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is way simpler than I thought.

1. Right-click the task and choose **Parametrize...**
2. Choose the property to be parametrized. From there you can choose an existing parameter or create a new one. It is easy-peasy.

In this case I created a boolean parameter and gave it the default value of FALSE. Then I bound it to the property Disable of the task. When the task is disabled it skips that task but any connections after the task continues.

Comment: Upvoted. Simple and helped me out. Thanks.